# Select a tag and then select popular and the tag description remains

Tags: bug, new-nav

Select a tag e.g. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on MSE then click on the popular tab.

The description for feature-request is still displayed but the questions are no longer [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions.

[image]